# An alternative to add digits to phone number string using swift

Tags: regex, swift

I have strings with stores phone numbers with formats:

- (14) 99999-9999
- +55 (14) 9999-9999
- +55 (14) 99999-9999
- 99999-9999

Than i need to make an algorithm to add 9090/90 before de 9999-9999 to get the results:

- **90** (14) 99999-9999
- +55 **90**(14) 9999-9999
- +55 **90**(14) 99999-9999
- **9090** 99999-9999

I know how to do it using an algorithm, but i need to know if i can do with a easiest and better way (like use regex).

Comment: specify your rules more precisely: When do you want to add 90 and when 9090? Are you getting these numbers as separate Strings or are you reading them in from a file - and if so, how are they delimited?

Comment: Is a contact phone number, some times it can be (14) 99999-9999, sometimes +55 (14) 9999-9999 etc. The rule is simple, when i have (14) in the string i need to add 90. When it doesnt exist add 9090. I can do a big algorithm to do it, but can i make a simple solution using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression match:

```
let str = "+55 (14) 99999-9999"
let optRange = str.rangeOfString("[(]14[)]", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
if let range = optRange? {
    let prefix = Range<String.Index>(start:str.startIndex, end:range.startIndex)
    let suffix = Range<String.Index>(start:range.startIndex, end:str.endIndex)
    let res = "\(str.substringWithRange(prefix))90 \(str.substringWithRange(suffix))"
    println(res)
}
```

This produces

```
+55 90 (14) 99999-9999
```

You would need an `else` branch to deal with the situation when the `(14)` substring is not found.